bypass an HVAC unit float switch (safe-t-switch)
how to bypass an HVAC unit float switch (safe-t-switch), yes I do understand the importance of the safety switch,  I am currently waiting for Amazon to deliver my replacement but in the meantime my house is a sauna with 4 adults 3 kids 2 cats 1 dog.

how do you know that the switch is defective?

Should be as easy as either connecting/disconnecting two wires.  Depends if the switch connects or disconnects the power.  Done with the breaker off.  4 adults should be able to keep an eye on it to turn off if needed.

These usually operate by opening the circuit. They can be defeated by shorting the two wires together. Either follow the two wires, see what they connect to, and connect those two things together -- or, just cut the two wires from the switch and join them with a wire nut.
Consider where and how you'll make the connection to install the new switch and make your switch bypass at that point.
